Spring Cloud Config client not able to connect to the Spring Cloud Config server
We are using spring-cloud-starter-config version 4.1.0 and spring-cloud-config-client version 4.1.0 .Configurations are maintained in Properties table of config_database.
Both our config server and config client microservice are running as pod in OpenShift environment. We don't have any issue when we are running one replica of config client, config client is successfully calling the config server rest api and getting the configuration parameter.
Problem starts when we are increasing the number of replica to 2 and starting both pod concurrently, in this case one of the pod gets the configuration from config server and other one fails and I find the below error message
main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader : Fetching config from server at : http://config-svc:7002/api/v1/ss/config/getServiceConfig 2024-04-04T00:17:11.240Z INFO 1 --- [projectmgr-svc] [ main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader : Exception on Url - http://config-svc:7002/api/v1/ss/config/getServiceConfig:org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://config-svc:7002/api/v1/ss/config/getServiceConfig/projectmgr-svc/DEV/1.0": config-svc. Will be trying the next url if available
We are using the service name of config server as both client and server are there in the same namespace.
Please let us know the corrective action which we should be taking to resolve this issue. Any help is much appreciated
Tried multiple test by bringing down the replica to 1 and it is working fine. It should even work when we have multiple replicas of config client as well.
